# Fork bent on a flat pack bike - what to do?

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, bso

I recently made a big mistake and bought a 27.5 Orkan 21 spd. MB. The box was beat up and the front forks where so bent and I couldn't put the front wheel on. Amazon gave me a full refund and didn't even want the bike back lol. Should I trash it or buy a new forkset?. P.S. put out real money and bought a real bike.

Comment: Some pictures would help us judging the status of your stuff way more than "box was beat up" and "fork was so bent".

Comment: Before you invest much more in either money or time, look *carefully* at the rest of the bike, to see if there are any other defects from the poor handling.

Comment: Lol I believe they do that when the costs of product underpass the cost of the shipping and handling.

Answer (score 18):

Your bike (27.5 Orkan 21 spd. MB) sells for less than US$150 and is shipped flat packed. This puts it firmly in what we call [BSO or bicycle shaped object](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bso) territory.

At US$150, it’s hard to find a repair that isn’t going to cost half as much that the bike is worth. You might have the best success going to a bike coop and finding a used fork for $10-20 (or free) and learning how to repair it yourself.

Or you could just donate the bike to the bike coop and they’d use it for donor parts. Or give it to someone as a project bike. The reality is that to get to the US$150 retail price point, the bike is value engineered to the hilt (likely $50 total landed) so is built with the absolute cheapest components and as a result isn’t  worth much. The reason amazon refunded your money is that the shipping back to them is more than the bike is worth.

[image: orkan mountainbike]

Comment: I love the term BSO